# Resolving data to use inside components in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I have an application where the main data is resolved using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) on a main state. This data is then stored in a `service` so I can access this data via `component`, `controller`, etc...

The problem I'm facing is during the first load. Since this data is get via `$http` requests, when the *app* starts, specially my `component`, the data isn't ready yet, therefor, the `component` has `undefined` data and doesn't render properly.

I could use `$onChange`, but since I'm not binding the data, but instead getting it from the `service`, I don't know how to do it the proper way.

For example, let's say I need to fill some information on the `footer` of the `index.html`, so I have a code like this:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    [..other elements..]

    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

footer.component.js

```
var footer = {
    /* @ngInject*/
    controller: function(storeFactory) {
        this.mainInfo = storeFactory.footerData;
    },
    template: `
        <div class="footer__content">
            {{ $ctrl.mainInfo }}
        </div>
    `
}

angular
    .module(appModule)
    .component('footer', footer);
```

If I use a `console.log` inside the `component`, the `this.mainInfo` is undefined, however, if I set a timeout I can get the data properly.

I know I can solve this in some ways, for example:

- $watch: Which I know isn't the best practice;
- Get the data inside the component, but it's going to repeat some `$http` a lot of times, because this problem happens in other components as weel;
- Use a $timeout, but I don't know how much time it's going to take to get the data, since it's done on the backend;
- Define a controller to pass the data via bindings, then I can use $onChange, but then again, I'll be repeating myself a lot;

What would be a better option to go around this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If storeFactory.footerData is undefined angular cant watch for changes because it cant inject itself to bind on literals. But if you assign the storeFactory Object angular has an object where it can register its two way databinding thingies.

```
var footer = {
    /* @ngInject*/
    controller: function(storeFactory) {
        this.mainInfo = storeFactory;
    },
    template: `
        <div class="footer__content">
            {{ $ctrl.mainInfo.footerData }}
        </div>
    `
}
```

Please let me know if that works, i had countless cases where this was the solution.

Another way would be to use events or the observer pattern to register your component at the service for updates.

Comment: Yes, it worked! In most of the cases this is enough, but there is one data that needs to be filtered. I was using $filter, and this is not working because of the way I receive the data. Currently I'm filtering the data within the resolve in uirouter, but do you recommend doing it in another way?

Comment: Or for example, I need to set a background image on the element, using $element.css, So i can just do this when the data is actually avaliable.

Comment: Thats my biggest critique with angular1. It's daunting to write filters and do everything in the template just to avoid having to write $watchers

Like i said, you could pre process your data in the service (may be bad), write your own observer pattern (to lazy for that) or use events (very maintainable... not)

Another way would be to go FRP and use observers. rxjs would be a way but i dont know if it plays nice with angular. Some are mixing ReactJS and Angular...